# Passing information from one storyboard to another

Tags: swift, func

I am having trouble passing the score to quiz app from a model page to one of my controllers. I have a counter that totals up the score, however when I try and add it to a label on another storyboard it takes the original declared value of zero rather than the updated version.

[This is where the function of counting is taking place and im just activating the function on another storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHy3W.png)

Comment: Multiple type of method for Storyboard data sharing - Follow this one : https://betterprogramming.pub/5-ways-to-pass-data-between-view-controllers-18acb467f5ec

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it will give you zero because there is no update in score variable.
One way to pass score from one view controller to other view controller is as:

1. create a variable in destination view controller
2. Initiate destination view controller from current controller.
3. Assign current score to destination view controller's variable before pushing or presenting it.
4. In viewdidload or wherever you want to display it, assign score to its label
   Here is sample code you can do:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVCID")
vc.anyVariableYouDeclare = currentScore
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response.

what would step two look like. The counter is in a VC called QuizViewController, while I want it to transfer to a VC called ResultsViewController. 

For step 4 would it be placed in the QuizViewcontroller?

Comment: Please share proper screenshots of the code, so that I can get what are you doing.